# Global variable in a static method

Tags: c#, static, console-application

This seems basic but Im finding this quite trivial.  Simply how would you recommend setting a global variable with a static class (i.e. console-application)?

To give you a little more background the main method is calling some custom eventhandlers that I hope to get / set the variables.

Any ideas or suggestions you have is appreciated.

Comment: I would personally recommend erasing the phrase "global variable" from your vocabulary.

Comment: for future reference, something that is trivial, is something you find to be simple.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simplest way is

```
public static Object MyGlobalVariable;
```

which creates a public static field.  A little better is:

```
public static Object MyGlobalVariable { get; set; }
```

Which creates a public static property.

Comment: Why is the property a little better?

Comment: @IllidanS4, stackoverflow.com/questions/653536/difference-between-property-and-field-in-c-sharp-3-0/653799

Comment: I know the difference, but are static properties objectively better than static fields?

Comment: @IllidanS4, for public data, yes.

Answer (score 13):

There are no global variables in C#.  A variable is always locally-scoped.  The fundamental unit of code is the class, and within a class you have fields, methods, and properties.

You *can* mimic a "global variable" by making a public static field or property in some class, but you *shouldn't*.  C# makes this difficult for a very good reason; global variables are pure evil.  They violate several good principles of OO design - encapsulation, loose coupling, and high cohesion, to name just a few.

I realize this is a beginner question, but I think it's *because* this is a beginner question that it's so important to be saying this.  Now is the best time to start learning what tactics are actively discouraged or even dangerous in C#, and using a static field/property as a global variable is about six of them.  There are legitimate uses for these constructs, but passing data around from place to place is not one of them.

If two different classes depend upon the same information, then *pass the information from the source to the destination*.  This is usually done either through the constructor or as an argument to the method being called.  You should always have one and only one instance that truly "owns" this information; making information "global" means that you can't reason about who or what might be depending on it at any given point in time.

Please consider this, and try to think about other ways you could share the information that you want to store in a global variable (i.e. by providing it as an argument to a constructor or method).  If you're not sure, post an example of what you're trying to do and we'll help out.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating.. that was very helpful.

Comment: Supposing I have a couple of threads running simultaneously and away from the main thread and now when there is a failure in either of those threads, I want to increase the failure count. How would this be done then?

Comment: @user20358: That's not really enough information to recommend a solution. What are the threads doing? Why would they fail? What are the consequences of failure? What precisely is the point of *counting* them, as opposed to logging them or taking some follow-up action? You should clarify your problem and ask a new question.

Comment: ^ In my case, I am incrementing the counter with each thread that is created, and then decrementing when each one finishes, and waiting for all to finish before executing another command.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure but you could try a singleton to hold your variables. Without knowing what you are trying to accomplish it's hard to recommend if this solution wouldn't bite you down the road.

http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html