# Global variables in Java

Tags: java, global-variables

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why are there no global variables in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581234/why-are-there-no-global-variables-in-java)
>   [Global variables in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646577/global-variables-in-java)

Hi,

Is there any way to declare global Variables in java? or something with a wide scope like them? can anybody explain me why are global variables considered bad? any articles about this are really appreciated.

thank you

Comment: Did you search a little? You're not the first to ask [why global variables are bad](http://www.google.ca/search?q=global+variable+are+bad) nor [how to use global variables in Java](http://www.google.ca/search?q=java+global+variable).

Comment: Search before you ask! http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=global+variables+java

Comment: (1) `public static`, (2) because anyone can play with them. You loose control, (3) If have to, use `public static final`.

Answer (score 1):

On any class, you can declare static variables:

```
class MyClass {

    public static String MyString = "Some String";

    ...
}
```

And then reference them via:

```
MyClass.MyString;
```

Comment: by the way, you have just defined a constant here. Its not a variable.

Comment: Oops, thank you :)... updated

Answer (score 0):

You can create 'global' variables by declaring them within the scope of the class ie

```
public class Example {
    String globalString = "this is global";
    public static void main(String[] args){
       String localString = "this is a local variable";
    }
}
```

You can also create static variables which can be accessed by a method which has been declared static too.

Comment: Its not global, as it can not be accessed outside the package. Even if you make that `public`, that will not make it a global variable whatsoever.

Comment: If you look at my last line, I say about static variables...

Comment: @user551841: Even `static` will not make that global, because we don't have "global" in Java. Please read the link, I provided. Its worth it.

Answer (score 0):

A good discussion can be found here, [Static Methods or Not? Global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222044/static-methods-or-not-global-variables/4222084#4222084)

Answer (score 0):

`public static` will give enough scope to your variable for them to act as global variable. But think twice before doing so.